# Shrink consecutive two rows of a Dataframe and replace the resulting column value with average of the consecutive rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I need to shrink every consecutive two rows of a dataframe and need to replace Marks column with average marks of two rows for each category. I am using Pyspark 2.4.4 on Azure Databricks. Any Idea how can I approach the same. My sample dataframe looks like below.

```
   +----------+-------+--------+
   | Category | Quiz  | Marks  |
   +----------+-------+--------+
   |    A     |   1   |   10   |
   |    A     |   2   |   20   |
   |    A     |   3   |   30   |
   |    A     |   4   |   40   |
   |    B     |   1   |   4    |
   |    B     |   2   |   2    |
   |    B     |   3   |   6    |
   |    B     |   4   |   8    |
   +----------+-------+--------+
```

My Dataframe will look like this

```
   +----------+-------+--------+
   | Category | QuiZ  | Marks  |
   +----------+-------+--------+
   |    A     |   1   |   15   |
   |    A     |   2   |   35   |
   |    B     |   1   |   3    |
   |    B     |   2   |   7    |
   +----------+-------+--------+

In genaral I have 10K categories and 300 quiz and marks for each category
```

Comment: If there were two more rows initially, `(A, 5, 50)` and `(A, 6, 60)` would you then see a record of `A, 3, 55` in the outcome?

Comment: Yes Oliver this would be the outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import libraries

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext('local')
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```

Create your dataframe

```
category = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
quiz = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
marks = [10, 20, 30, 40, 4, 2, 6, 8]
df = spark.createDataFrame(zip(category, quiz, marks), schema=['Category', 'Quiz', 'Marks'])

df.show()
+--------+----+-----+
|Category|Quiz|Marks|
+--------+----+-----+
|       A|   1|   10|
|       A|   2|   20|
|       A|   3|   30|
|       A|   4|   40|
|       B|   1|    4|
|       B|   2|    2|
|       B|   3|    6|
|       B|   4|    8|
+--------+----+-----+
```

decrease by one quiz number if even

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    "Quiz2",
    F.when(
        df['Quiz'] % 2 == 0,
        df['Quiz'] - 1
    ).otherwise(df['Quiz'])
)

df2.show()
+--------+----+-----+-----+
|Category|Quiz|Marks|Quiz2|
+--------+----+-----+-----+
|       A|   1|   10|    1|
|       A|   2|   20|    1|
|       A|   3|   30|    3|
|       A|   4|   40|    3|
|       B|   1|    4|    1|
|       B|   2|    2|    1|
|       B|   3|    6|    3|
|       B|   4|    8|    3|
+--------+----+-----+-----+
```

compute your final result

```
df_final = df2.groupBy(['Category', 'Quiz2']).agg({'Marks': 'mean'})
df_final.show()

+--------+-----+----------+
|Category|Quiz2|avg(Marks)|
+--------+-----+----------+
|       A|    3|      35.0|
|       B|    1|       3.0|
|       A|    1|      15.0|
|       B|    3|       7.0|
+--------+-----+----------+
```

Comment: I'm a bit surprised this is marked as the answer, as the result isn't what was asked. You also have a SyntaxError.

Comment: I wrote the code without testing it, now it is fixed. Thanks